# method can't be called from inside for loop?

Tags: python

I really don't now why I can't call the method `setTRSKey` from inside my for loop. Am I missing something? This makes no sense to me at all. Pycharm declares it as an **unsolved reference**

Here is the code:

```
import math
import nuke

originNode = nuke.selectedNode()
world_matrix = originNode['world_matrix']  # this is an iArray Knob with 16 fields
mResult = nuke.math.Matrix4()  # Matrix to copy iArray to

# Ask user for Frame Range operation
ret = nuke.getFramesAndViews('Frame range', '%s-%s' % (nuke.root().firstFrame(), nuke.root().lastFrame()))

if ret != None:

    nuke.nodeCopy("%clipboard%")  # creating node duplicate
    originNode.setSelected(False)
    newNode = nuke.nodePaste("%clipboard%")  # creating origin node duplicate
    newNode['translate'].clearAnimated()
    newNode['translate'].setValue(0)
    newNode['translate'].setAnimated()
    newNode['rotate'].clearAnimated()
    newNode['rotate'].setValue(0)
    newNode['rotate'].setAnimated()
    newNode['scaling'].clearAnimated()
    newNode['scaling'].setValue(0)
    newNode['scaling'].setAnimated()

    frange = nuke.FrameRange(ret[0])  # convert to frange object
    for frame in frange:
        for i in xrange(0, 16):
            mResult[i] = world_matrix.valueAt(frame)[i]

        mResult.transpose()  # row become columns and vice versa
        mTranslate = nuke.math.Matrix4(mResult)
        mTranslate.translationOnly()
        mRotate = nuke.math.Matrix4(mResult)
        mRotate.rotationOnly()
        mScale = nuke.math.Matrix4(mResult)
        mScale.scaleOnly()

        translate = (mTranslate[12], mTranslate[13], mTranslate[14])
        rotateRad = mRotate.rotationsZXY()
        rotate = (math.degrees(rotateRad[0]), math.degrees(rotateRad[1]),
                  math.degrees(rotateRad[2]))  # convert from radiants to defrees
        scale = (mScale.xAxis().x, mScale.yAxis().y, mScale.zAxis().z)

        setTRSKey(frame, translate, rotate, scale)
else:
    print "User canceled the operation"

def setTRSKey(frame, translate, rotate, scale):
    print type(translate(0))

    newNode['translate'].setValueAt(translate(0), frame, 0)
    newNode['translate'].setValueAt(translate(1), frame, 1)
    newNode['translate'].setValueAt(translate(2), frame, 2)
```

edit: Example with classes where **loadDataFromScript** is called before defining

```
class Connecthor(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
#
allowedNodes = ["Read", "Write", "Merge", "Keymix", "ChannelMerge", "Roto", "RotoPaint", "Copy", "Shuffle", "PostageStamp", "Camera", "Camera2", "ScanlineRender", "Connector", "ReadGeo", "ReadGeo2", "BackdropNode"]
script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

#constructor
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Connecthor, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.setFixedSize(self.size())
    #self.setWindowOpacity(0.95)
    popupmenu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.btn_settings)
    #popupmenu.addAction("save links for script", self.writeListDictToJson)
    #popupmenu.addAction("import links from json", self.readJsonToDict)
    popupmenu.addAction("save links for script (manual)", self.saveDatatoScript)
    popupmenu.addAction("settings", self.opensetting)
    self.btn_settings.setMenu(popupmenu)
    self.btn_settings.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(os.path.join(iconpath, "settings.png")))
    self.btn_addSelectedNodes.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(os.path.join(iconpath, "add.png")))
    self.btn_addSelectedNodes.clicked.connect(self.addSelectedNodes)

    # #Loading test Json
    #self.readJsonToDict()
    self.loadDataFromScript()
```

Comment: Python does not hoist function definitions.

Comment: You're calling the function before it's declared; Python parses (almost) everything strictly from top to bottom.

Comment: Function definitions are executed. A function whose definition has not yet been executed does not exist.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand. I often call methods which are only defined later in the code and never had a single problem with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python you must define functions before they are called. Move your `setTRSKey` definition above the `for` loop. Generally speaking, function definitions are one of the very first things in the file after imports, though this is not always the case.

Comment: Is this different if I have classes? Because I often call other methods before they are defined and never had a problem with this if it's a class method?

Comment: @J. Stacky Can you provide a specific example?

Comment: @ J. Stacky that is because you are defining a constructor (telling it what to do), not calling the function (telling it to execute). If you tried to create a `Connecthor` object before `loadDataFromScript` was defined you would get an error. This is impossible because `loadDataFromScript` is a class method and is already defined inside the class.